# How get managed type from type name in Javers

Tags: javers

I need to map TpyeName to Class ?
JaversCore#getTypeMapping implement such function but is not public (JaversCore is not public).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this method is not present in the Javers interface. You can crate a PR which adds it and push it here: https://github.com/javers/javers. I will merge it.

Comment: I mean getTypeMapping(String) which is not exposed by the API (Javers).

Comment: It is exposed and it is public, see https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/3e43ea0ed532481d95a508befbb56760e4c0affd/javers-core/src/main/java/org/javers/core/Javers.java#L610

Comment: Please see my screenshot, I am asking about JaversCore#getTypeMapping(String) (not Javers#getTypeMapping(Type))

Comment: JaversCore is not public, and it should not be. You are expected to use the Javers interface.

Comment: We do not need that JaversCore be public. Otherwise, we need to add getTypeMapping(String) to the interface Javers.

Comment: Check the code, as I wrote in my answer, this method is part of the Javers API an it is public in the Javers interface.

Comment: Did you read my comment, please! I am talking about getTypeMapping(String) and not getTypeMapping(Type) !

Comment: sorry, you are right, this method is not present to the Javers interface. You can crate a PR here https://github.com/javers/javers . I will merge it